# Fully automatic updates in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, updates, automation

It is really annoying to click the update icon and enter password every time to confirm updates.

How can I setup fully automatic updates without any prompts? (Not only security updates)
Some small notification about finished updates would also be nice.

I'm using Kubuntu 11.04 and KPackageKit.

Comment: There are some scripts floating around on the net. I'd suggest googling 'apt-get update', 'script', 'automate' and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open the file manager as super user, e.g. `sudo dolphin`
  <sup>**Be careful with such instance of file manager because you may delete something important and break your system**</sup>
- Create a file named `autoupdate` in `/etc/cron.*` (where `*` is `hourly`, `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly` depending on your preference). I used `/etc/cron.hourly/`.
- Put the following contents into the file:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  apt-get update
  apt-get upgrade -y
  apt-get autoclean
  ```

  ... and save it.
- Allow the file to be executed in its properties, or by using this: `sudo chmod 755 autoupdate`

And that's it! You will have your software automatically updated without any notifications
(of course, if you've turned off the notifications in update settings).
<sub>Thanks to [boehj](https://askubuntu.com/users/12473/boehj) for the source of information: [Automatic Weekly Package Updates Using Cron And Apt-Get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo#Advanced%20Alternative:%20Automatic%20Weekly%20Package%20Updates%20Using%20Cron%20And%20Apt-Get)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

- Open `Kpackagekit`
- Uncheck confirmation dialog when installing or updating packages.
- Uncheck Notify when updates available.
- check all updates.

[image]

Comment: I think I've tried this, but there were simply no updates happening (I saw available updates piling up)

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Well, if this doesn't work,maybe it is a bug. Also try the suggested idea by boehj above.Or wait for another answer.

Comment: I'll take a look for a good script today if I get the time. There are plenty out there.

Comment: @binarylife Nope, this doesn't work. I have 6 updates hanging there right now.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: mmm, this could be a bug.But edit your question with this new information so it'll get more attention and more answers.

Comment: @boehj Where is your good script? This answer doesn't work.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: I haven't had time, but a Google search with 'apt-get update script automate' just now turned up some pages that may be useful. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo) was the first result. Take a look at the section entitled "Advanced Alternative: Automatic Weekly Package Updates Using Cron And Apt-Get". That may be of use to you.

Comment: @boehj I always search before asking here. I've seen that page, but was afraid to try. Now I did try it, and we will see in an hour if it works.

Comment: @Blaxpirit: I hope it works out. Let us know if it does or doesn't.

Comment: @boehj It does work. I've simplified the information there and put it into an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45797/fully-automatic-updates-in-kubuntu/47039#47039)

Comment: @Blax: Good to hear.